# How to limit a Jquery effect to one item at a time?

Tags: jquery

I have a set of divs with a hovering effect, but if you hover over them quickly the animation just gets messy. This is the HTML:

```
<a>
     <div class="project">
        <img src="img/projects/TrendyPhones.png" alt="project screenshot">
        <h3>Trendy Phones</h3>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="">
    <div class="project">
        <img src="img/projects/TrendyPhones.png" alt="project screenshot">
        <h3>Trendy Phones</h3>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="">
    <div class="project">
        <img src="img/projects/TrendyPhones.png" alt="project screenshot">
        <h3>Trendy Phones</h3>
    </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.project').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('h3').fadeIn(500); 
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('h3').fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) the running animation before beginning the newer one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.project').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('h3').stop().fadeIn(500); 
  }, function(){
    $(this).find('h3').stop().fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That actually did it.

Comment: @AbderrahimGadmy Glad to help! :)

Comment: @techie_28 Thank you. I was actually waiting for the 15 minutes time limit to expire so I can accept the answer, and just forgot to check back.